# php xpath - get only tag attributes/remove inner tag contents

Tags: php

How do I:

1. Hide everything between between the head tags in xpath "/html/head" query?

For example on "`<html><head><title>some title</title>some text</head>`..." will produce nodeValue = "some title some text" which is irrelevant because I just need the tag attributes and I don't need to add irrelevant data to my database.

2. Hide all child/descendant nodes in xpath "/html/body" query?

For example on "`<html><body><div>some anchor</div>some text</body>`..." will produce nodeValue = "some anchor some text" "some text" is relevant to the body tag and I do need to keep it and get ride of everything else.

Also I don't want to remove them from the dom document altogether!

Comment: You don't want to store it in your database, but you would like the DOM intact? WFT? Maybe you should tell us what you're actually trying to acomplish, as your question as it stands make very little sense? PHP has many ways of using XPath, through the DOM reader, through the SimpleXML object, through XSLT, and depending on PHP version, through various brew styles. Which one(s) are you using?

Comment: Because if its not intact how do I read those childs tag as I traverse the tree later on. I'm breaking up each tag into all its attributes and contents but not the descendants associated with it. The head tag is different because any direct text placed in it should be ignored. So if I have a function to traverse each tag in the html document it will always ask for all the tags and contents unless I somehow specify otherwise.

Comment: Well, the reason I asked for what you're trying to accomplish and what PHP versions and environment you've got, is that this is trivial stuff in XSLT, possibly even easy enough in SimpleXML as well, but before I spend lots of time crunching it it would be great with a few directional hints. :)

Comment: What do you mean you just need the tag attributes? Do you mean you need the element name? Or you want things like class/id/checked? And when you say you just need the tag attributes, you don't need the node text or the element name at all? You want a database of just "class : foo | id : bar? Or are you trying to build a DB with rows like: "title: 'some web page'; content: 'basic content';" etc etc? Keep in mind that if you ignore descendant elements and you need the actual text inside the node, that you would lose any text within the main p tag wrapped in a span tag.

Answer (score 2):

> which is irrelevant because I just need the tag attributes

I am not sure where are the attributes in your example. And am no PHP xpath implementation expert.

However you may try the following:

- use the `text()` xpath function at the end of your expression (e.g. `"/html/head/text()"`) to get only the text nodes, not tags
- the xpath function should return a NodeList. You shoud use that to get an entire fragment XML - e.g. [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/domxpath) does just that.

Answer (score 1):

In that case perhaps a preg_match like this one might be what you need?

```
preg_match( '/<head (.*)>/', $file_contents, $matches );
echo ( isset( $matches[1] ) ) ? $matches[1] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
About the head element - you want to get only the attributes of the head element, you can use xpath( "//head" ) [and then $head->attributes](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-attributes.php).

I won't directly answer your question which is not very full of details, but I will rather tell a story about my own experience. I believe that you can solve your problems if you understand the implications of the examples I am giving.

I understand from the tags that you want to use PHP on the job. I had a similar problem lately, where I had to parse around 100 static html documents, and extract parts of the information to place it in a database. Initially I thought about regular expressions, but as I went along I saw that will be a tedious task.

So I ended up messing with XPath and SimpleXML in PHP.

Here is how I ended up:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents( $file );
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $file_contents );
$document = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );
```

Now I have a SimpleXML object which holds the HTML code. That is really great - here is how it rolls:

suppose you have the following html code:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="description">
    <dl>
        <dt>Title</dt>
        <dd>
            <ul><li> first item </li> <li> second item</li></ul>
            <p> a paragraph.. </p>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, you can iterate over all the <dl> elements in your code, which are children of div#description and grandchildren of div#content like that:

```
foreach( $document->xpath( "//div[@id='content']/div[@class='description']/dl" ) as $element )
```

and then all the children are parsed through a recursive function like this one:

```
function recurse( $parent )
{
echo '<' . $parent->getName() . '>' . "\n";
#echo $parent # you might want to strip any white spaces like \t and \n here

foreach( $parent->children() as $child )
{
    if( count( $child->children() ) > 0 )
    {
        recurse( $child );
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<' . $child->getName() . '>';
       echo $child;
       echo '</' . $child->getName() . '>' . "\n";
    }
}
echo '</' . $parent->getName() . '>' . "\n";
}
```

I hope that I've been of help, good luck!

Comment: regards your edit - yes that is true but it is part of a function that traverses the html tree structure which means it will add the information whether I want it or not, unless I specify every type of tag (node) I want it to ignore (which is annoying to me :) )